# Compare two language strings

Tags: c++, string, wmi

We are working on a remote manmagment software. We require to compare the data we get from the remote system. We are using C++ and WMI to get data from remote system. WHen processing the data we may need to compare certain words (against constant words we have) from the data collected from remote system. When the host and target systems are in English language, we have no issues in compare the strings.

But when the remote computer returns data other than english, our comparision is failed. We thought of implementing localization and keep all possible language strings with us, . And if, one of the strings in our list maches, we can proceed. But it is very tedious process.

Is there any way to compare strings from two differnt languages in C++ or WMI...?

Any APIs..? OR Workarounds...?

Please help!

Comment: What kind of data are you comparing? What are you trying to do with this comparison?

Comment: Why don't rewrite sending system to send you some kind of error code, not localized string

Comment: I'll echo Michael in asking what the data are like.  Does  `"But when the remote computer returns data other than english"` mean language-wise or encoding-wise?

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. Jonsca, We are trying to get information from WMIC commandline tool from Linux (open source wmic client tool.) We get error in strings like 'Access Denied'instead of error code(Hexcode) in that tool. When we connect to german OS, the 'Access Denied' string is in German. We are blocked here.

Answer (score 0):

There are c# facilities for comparing strings in a locale, or culture-specific way, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx#Y472)  which gives an example of a comparison between two german strings treating the different representations of "ss" and the essettz character 'ß'as equivalent.

To do this you need to have knowledge of the language of the host computer, it's debatable if you should treat ss and 'ß'as equal if you are not working in German.

But I'm not clear to whether you have this kind of problem. Are you in fact hoping to actually translate the text you receive? So on you machine you have a list of strings:

```
RED
GREEN
WHITE
```

and you might receive from the host RED or ROUGE or ROT. In which case I don't really see you have much option but to keep a translation table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [std::locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/locale/) and its various features ([operator()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/locale/operator%28%29/)). I suppose you also want to use std::wstring instead of usual std::string to support UTF-like characters.

Comment: The locale doesn't help much here. I am in a Swedish locale, but write this in English anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Windows Management Instrumentation: International Support Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742611.aspx). The need for localization, and the resulting need for cross-locale support has been noted before.